# No cambia la imagen al hacer un set en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Lo que trato de hacer es que cuando se cumpla alguna condicion se haga un cambio de imagen a otra.Pero no me hace ningun cambio, y no sé porque, si alguien me podría indicar donde me equivoco o si el tipo de set no es compatible y tal le estaría muy agradecido, os dejo adjunto el codigo:

```
languages=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spLanguage);
        items= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.language);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvIdioma);
        image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bandera);
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        languages.setAdapter(adapter);
        languages.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(Spinner parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String text;
                text= (String) parent.getSelectedItem();
                if(text.equals("Spanish")){
                    image.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable));
                }else{
                    if(text.equals("English")){
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.gb);
                    }
                }
                tv.setText(text);
            }
        });
```

Mirad en el metodo del Spinner:

```
languages.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(Spinner parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String text;
                text= (String) parent.getSelectedItem();
                if(text.equals("Spanish")){
                    image.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable));
                }else{
                    if(text.equals("English")){
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.gb);
                    }
                }
                tv.setText(text);
            }
    })
```

Comment: Imprime text y verifica que realmente tenga el texto Spanish o English, si es necesario, has un trim() a text, puede que exista un espacio.

Answer (score 1):

En ambos casos intenta con:

```
image.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gb));
```

o

```
image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gb);
```

Si es necesario has un trim a text para eliminar los espacios

```
text = text.trim();
```

Comment: @Geany Has verificado que realmente entre al if? image.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable)); //Esto no te marca un error?